# Is there any way to skip 0's while plotting in chart control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a chart control in my asp.net page. I want a way to skip all 0's while binding chart control.

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtBiometricsProgress" runat="server" Height="650px" Width="1000px">
  <Series> 
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" BorderWidth="5" ChartType="Line" LegendText="Weight" YValueMembers="Weight">
    </asp:Series> 
    <asp:Series Name="Series2" BorderWidth="5" ChartType="Line" LegendText="Waist" YValueMembers="Waist">
    </asp:Series> 
  </Series> 
  <ChartAreas> 
     <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false"> 
       <AxisX Interval="1" Title="Biometrics Progress">
       </AxisX> 
     </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
   <Legends> 
      <asp:Legend > 
      </asp:Legend> 
   </Legends> 
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to collect and bind the data?

Comment: I have inserted the code from the comment into the post, but we still lack information on how you bind your data.

Comment: There are no Direct Method for Avoiding Zeros while Plotting .
You Need to Write Method which converts your Datapoints to Non-Zero DPs.

Comment: Please provide me that method which converts Datapoints to Non-Zero DPs.

Comment: Please provide me the method for converting Datapoints to Non-Zero DPs.